# jupyter command not found in terminal MacOS

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, zshrc, nbconvert

For some reason, when I pip3 everything, it goes all under this PATH `/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/bin` 
same for my notebook.

So I opened my vscode and go to `.zshrc` and add `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/bin` to my path.

And I go to terminal  `jupyter notebook` I got `zsh: /Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/bin/jupyter: bad interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3: no such file or directory`

And then I go back to `.zshrc` and change the path to `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/bin/jupyter-notebook` and I add to the path, it got `zsh: command not found: jupyter`

I refuse to use conda.. no particular reason.

What should I do next?

**UPDATE**

The actual reason I want to solve above issue is because I have my jupyter kernel running fine in my VS code, but cannot convert to HTML. That's why I thought install web-based Jupyter Notebook can help me solve this issue. Apparently, it did not. when I try to convert to HTML in web-based notebook, it give me the `500 Internal Error`.

I also tried something like this `python3 -m jupyter nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb`
And I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'template_paths'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 270, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 664, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 350, in start
    self.convert_notebooks()
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 518, in convert_notebooks
    cls = get_exporter(self.export_format)
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 102, in get_exporter
    if getattr(exporter(config=config), 'enabled', True):
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 325, in __init__
    super().__init__(config=config, **kw)
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 114, in __init__
    self._init_preprocessors()
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 491, in _init_preprocessors
    conf = self._get_conf()
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 507, in _get_conf
    for path in map(Path, self.template_paths):
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 518, in _template_paths
    template_names = self.get_template_names()
  File "/Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 601, in get_template_names
    raise ValueError('No template sub-directory with name %r found in the following paths:\n\t%s' % (base_template, paths))
ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'lab' found in the following paths:
    /Users/zhengyangzhang/Library/Jupyter
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
```

Can someone take a look again and see what's the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

OK, some things to look at.  First this is what my path on OSX looks like (`bash` but last time I checked `zsh` is highly compatible):

```
showpath ()
{
    IFS=':' read -a array <<< "$PATH";
    for index in "${!array[@]}";
    do
        echo "$index ${array[index]}";
    done
}
```

```
$ showpath 
(some stuff removed)
1 /opt/local/bin   I use macports, this is where MY Python is
2 /usr/local/bin   and also brew, probably where your Python is
3 /usr/bin
4 /bin
5 /usr/sbin
6 /sbin
8 /opt/local/sbin
10 /Users/xxx/bin
11 /Users/xxx/Library/Python/3.8/bin   this also needs to be on your path
```

OK, now, after deactivating my virtualenv, this is what I see:

```
$ which python3.8
/opt/local/bin/python3.8  # you'll be in /usr/local/bin if using brew
which pip3
/Users/xxx/Library/Python/3.8/bin/pip3
```

If I `ls | egrep  'jupyter|pip3'` in `/Users/xxx/Library/Python/3.8/bin` I get:

```
jupyter
jupyter-bundlerextension
jupyter-console
jupyter-kernel
jupyter-kernelspec
jupyter-migrate
jupyter-nbconvert
jupyter-nbextension
jupyter-notebook
jupyter-qtconsole
jupyter-run
jupyter-serverextension
jupyter-troubleshoot
jupyter-trust
pip3
pip3.8
```

So, basically, if you can see `pip3` from the shell, your path should work for `jupyter` as well.

Now, if you are using brew, that's where `/usr/local/bin/python3` comes in.  And that should already be on your path, courtesy of `brew`.  I am *guessing* you have a `python3.8` entry there, but no `python3`.

#### Suggestion:

Maybe you should try to symlink via `ln -s python3.8 python3` in that directory and that will make jupyter see that plain old `python3` it wants.  You may have to `sudo` to get that link working (if so make sure your user has appropriate permissions on the link).

Also, to see things from plain old Python point of view:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for v in sys.path: print(v)
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload

 this is a deeper-level sibling of where the `bin` for Python keeps the 
executables like pip3 and jupyter
/Users/xxx/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages  


/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-package
```

Also, something else to look at.  Remember that `which jupyter`?

Let's look at what it says, and mostly at its shebang.

```
$ pwd
/Users/xxx/Library/Python/3.8/bin
$ cat jupyter
#!/opt/local/bin/python3.8   that's mine, but guessing 
                            #yours says `/usr/local/bin/python3`


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from jupyter_core.command import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: It’s a day I hoped I’d never see: emojis in code blocks.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for Notebook Unable to start from Terminal:**

After `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/bin` is in your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` (if you're using bash), you go back to your terminal and run  `python3 -m jupyter notebook`

And then the notebook will start.

Answer (score 1):

After typing in `jupyter --version` I realized that jupyter lab is not fully installed.

```
jupyterlab       : not installed
```

I installed it with:

```
pip3 install jupyterlab
```

I am using macOS Monterey.